# C++ printing spaces or tabs given a user input integer

Tags: c++, tabs

I need to turn user input (a number) into an output of TAB spaces.
Example I ask user:

```
cout << "Enter amount of spaces you would like (integer)" << endl;
cin >> n;
```

the (n) i need to turn it into an output like:

```
cout << n , endl;
```

and what prints on the screen would be the spaces
ex 
input is 5 
out put |**_**| <~~~there are five spaces there.

Sorry If I can't be clear, probably this is the reason I haven't been able to find an answer looking through other people's questions.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
cout << "Enter amount of spaces you would like (integer)" << endl; 
cin >> n;
//print n spaces
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
   cout << " " ;
}
cout <<endl;
```

Answer (score 75):

Just use `std::string`:

```
std::cout << std::string( n, ' ' );
```

In many cases, however, depending on what comes next, is may be
simpler to just add `n` to the parameter to an `std::setw`.

Answer (score 7):

I just happened to look for something similar and came up with this:

```
std::cout << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(n) << ' ';
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need a loop that iterates the number of times given by `n` and prints a space each time. This would do:

```
while (n--) {
  std::cout << ' ';
}
```

Comment: If n < 0 then your loop will not finish.

Comment: @secuman It will someday.

Answer (score 2):

You can use C++ manipulator setw(n) function which stands for set width to print n spaces.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int n;
  std::cin>>n; 
  cout<<"Here is "<<n <<" spaces "<<setw(n)<<":";
}
```

And don't forget to include C++ Library -

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSO8R.png)

Answer (score 0):

Appending single space to output file with stream variable.

`// declare output file stream varaible and open file
ofstream fout;
fout.open("flux_capacitor.txt");
fout << var << " ";`

Answer (score 0):

Simply add spaces for { 2 3 4 5 6 } like these:

```
cout<<"{";

for(){
    cout<<" "<<n;    //n is the element to print !
}

cout<<" }";
```

Comment: Use [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Your for loop is not correctly written.