# Putting spaces before two cout statement iterations that is displayed via a recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion

Essentially I am making some recursive calls where it increments and decrements a number that is displayed via cout statements. There are two cout statement iterations(so four of one cout statement, and four of the other) that display this. The first one increments the number from 1 to 4, and the second one decrements the number from 4 to 1. What I want to happen is for each cout statement, depending on the number, I want that many spaces before that specific cout function, except that value minus one. The difference between the first and second cout function is that the second cout function will also print out ALSO(will make sense later when I show my intended output.)

So this is the intended output of the cout functions(the stuff in parentheses is not meant to be taken literally. I was unable to just put spaces behind them because it wouldn't show for some reason. The first and last sentences of the output should have zero spaces behind it.):

This was written by call number 1.

(one space here)This was written by call number 2.

(two spaces here)This was written by call number 3.

(three spaces here)This was written by call number 4.

(three spaces here)This ALSO was written by call number 4.

(two spaces here)This ALSO was written by call number 3.

(one space here)This ALSO was written by call number 2.

This ALSO was written by call number 1.

Here is my code that accomplishes all this EXCEPT the spaces(There should be iostream with the angled brackets surrounding it after include, but it refuses to show for some reason.):

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

void Waswritten(int numwrite);


int main()

{

    Waswritten(4);

    return 0;

}


void Waswritten(int numwrite)

{

    static int count = 0;

    if (!numwrite)

        return;

    cout << "This was written by call number " << ++count << "." << endl;

    Waswritten(numwrite - 1);

    cout << "This ALSO was written by call number " << count-- << "." << endl;


}
```

Comment: What did you attempt to do, to solve this problem, and why didn't such solution work for you? For example, do any of the solutions, outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884284/c-printing-spaces-or-tabs-given-a-user-input-integer work for you?

Comment: I tried putting spaces before the cout statements in my code, but that adds spaces to all of them(depending on if I added spaces in the first iteration of them or the second). It essentially repeats the same cout statement four items for each iteration, so changing one via that method changes all of them. I wouldn't know how else to do it in a specific manner to each individual cout statement that is shown in the output.

Comment: "but that adds spaces to all of them" I am not sure, that I follow. Isn't it what you want? You want to prefix 0, 1, 2, ..., x spaces to all strings printed. So, what is the problem? Unless you implemented said functionality wrong. So please show it, so we can help you fix it. Or, alternatively, you can look at the answers, on the question, that I linked, to see if any solution, there, works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call this method from Waswritten

```
void writeSpaces(int spaceCount){
    for(int i=0;i<spaceCount;i++){
        cout<<" ";
    }   
}
```

before each cout

```
writeSpaces(count);
```

Comment: You could also get rid of the for loop if you use std::string(spaceCount, ' ');

Comment: This solution really helped! Although I had to make two seperate functions so I can call the 1 to 4 spacing properly for the first cout statements, and the reverse for the other cout statements, this worked exactly the way I wanted it to! Thank you so much!